# Getting an error with the AWS SDK for Translate

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

So I'm trying to do a simple text translation and I'm getting a stack error with data is undefined but that's not terribly descriptive or maybe I'm missing something. I'm fairly new to javascript so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm usually doing python stuff.

Code:

```
        translateText() {
            console.log(this.initialText) // text is correct
            console.log(aws_region) // region is correct

            // Get Credentials
            const credentials = Auth.currentCredentials()
            console.log(credentials) // credentials are correct

            // instantiate Translate
            const translate = new Translate({
                apiVersion: '2017-07-01',
                credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
                region: aws_region
            });

            // set params
            const params = {
                Text: this.initialText,
                SourceLanguageCode: 'en',
                TargetLanguageCode: 'es'
            }
            console.log(params) // params are correct

            // translate text
            const translation = translate.translateText(params,
                function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("error:" + err.message, err.stack);
                    }
                    if (data) {
                        console.log("Initial Text: " + this.initialText);
                        console.log("Translated Text: " + data.TranslatedText)
                    }
            });
        }
```

Stack Trace:

```
error:data is undefined isEmptyData@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-crypto/sha256-browser/build/isEmptyData.js:8:5
Sha256.prototype.update@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-crypto/sha256-browser/build/webCryptoSha256.js:21:27
Sha256.prototype.update@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-crypto/sha256-browser/build/crossPlatformSha256.js:23:19
hmac@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/credentialDerivation.js:93:10
getSigningKey/</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/credentialDerivation.js:40:42
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53
__awaiter/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:98:71
__awaiter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:94:12
getSigningKey@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/credentialDerivation.js:35:155
SignatureV4.prototype.getSigningKey@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/SignatureV4.js:270:91
SignatureV4.prototype.signRequest/</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/SignatureV4.js:208:86
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53
fulfilled@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:95:58
promise callback*step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:97:91
fulfilled@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:95:47
promise callback*step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:97:91
fulfilled@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:95:47
promise callback*step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:97:91
__awaiter/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:98:13
__awaiter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:94:12
SignatureV4.prototype.signRequest@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/SignatureV4.js:178:71
SignatureV4.prototype.sign/</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/SignatureV4.js:98:48
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53
__awaiter/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:98:71
__awaiter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:94:12
SignatureV4.prototype.sign@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/es/SignatureV4.js:89:71
awsAuthMiddleware/</</</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist/es/middleware.js:37:57
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53
fulfilled@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:95:58
promise callback*step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:97:91
__awaiter/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:98:13
__awaiter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:94:12
awsAuthMiddleware/</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist/es/middleware.js:16:75
_loop_1/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/es/defaultStrategy.js:87:62
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:109:139
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53
fulfilled@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:95:58
promise callback*step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:97:91
__awaiter/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:98:13
__awaiter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:94:12
StandardRetryStrategy.prototype.retry@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/es/defaultStrategy.js:64:71
retryMiddleware/</</</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/es/retryMiddleware.js:12:53
step@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-translate/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23
translate.vue:65
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data is undefined
    isEmptyData isEmptyData.js:8
    update webCryptoSha256.js:21
    update crossPlatformSha256.js:23
    hmac credentialDerivation.js:86
    getSigningKey credentialDerivation.js:33
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:74
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:70
    getSigningKey credentialDerivation.js:28
    getSigningKey SignatureV4.js:257
    signRequest SignatureV4.js:195
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:71
    promise callback*step tslib.es6.js:73
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:71
    promise callback*step tslib.es6.js:73
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:71
    promise callback*step tslib.es6.js:73
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:74
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:70
    signRequest SignatureV4.js:165
    sign SignatureV4.js:85
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:74
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:70
    sign SignatureV4.js:76
    awsAuthMiddleware middleware.js:31
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:71
    promise callback*step tslib.es6.js:73
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:74
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:70
    awsAuthMiddleware middleware.js:10
    _loop_1 defaultStrategy.js:74
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    step tslib.es6.js:85
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:71
    promise callback*step tslib.es6.js:73
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:74
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:70
    retry defaultStrategy.js:51
    retryMiddleware retryMiddleware.js:7
    step tslib.es6.js:100
isEmptyData.js:8
```

I'm following twitch example from the AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/examples-twitch.html

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the internal function into an arrow function and now it works appropriately.

```
const request = translate.translateText(params, 
    (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
           console.log("error:" + err.message, err.stack);
        }
        if (data) {
           console.log(data);
           console.log("Initial Text: " + this.initialText); // this 'this' doesn't
           console.log("Translated Text: " + data.TranslatedText);
           this.outputText = data.TranslatedText;
         }
});
```